# I need to store 154 images for my android app, what is the best way to do this?

Tags: android

I am making an android app which will need to display images for each item in a database which is currently 154 records long.

Now if I put the images into the database I would still have to store them in the resources to insert them when the app is first downloaded, I want to store this database locally on the app as the records are not likely to change and if the user doesn't have access to the internet they can still display some information.

Basically, I am wondering if storing these images in the local resources is the best way to go about it as having 154 images stored locally seems like a lot.

Comment: you don't have any other option!!

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! Makes things much easier then!

Comment: storing in resources is easier as compared to storing in database

Comment: `sqlite` search on google

Comment: you need to download all images and save those images to sd card or internal memory then make a record of stored images either in sqlite or make a ArrayList<images name or images path> save that list to sharedprefrence may be this will help you, when ever you need to see then you can see all images use image load from internal sd card or internal ImageLoader to get all images ..

Comment: Don't try to store the images in SQLITE, i have some problems to retrieve large data (such a base 64 String), instead, store the images in the file system and store the path in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do care for `apk size` then do not put these images `static`. Instead you can keep these images on `server`(your or free server) and easily load those images using libraries like `Glide` or `Picasso`.

If you think `apk size` will doesn't matter for you and user should not face problem due to unavailability of internet then you can keep those images static inside app iteself.

Answer (score 0):

here the best example with glide library.. i hope it might help

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

```
and for the apk size you can shrink image app easily with progurd
```

Answer (score 0):

When designing an app that stores images and cache it for later used, I will not think of how many images in my server are, but I will think how much `is my current phone capacity`. *Is it enough? Do I need to do some compression?*

Here are some of basic guides upon building. Note : these key points are intended only for simple app architecture since discussing a complex app architecture might need a longer answer format.

1. Check if SD card is mounted. *Note: I know you can store images through phone default storage but as much as possible don't use it because it is reserve for the OS.*
2. Before storing the image query first its size and compare to the phone's current memory `if(image.size <= phoneMem) save() else discard()`. You can also check about `StatFS` usage.
3. If you feel that you wanted to store more images then use any Image compression algorithm. You can find many of those like [Lossess Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression).